# Getting ProjectWeaverXml Error when Building C# Project with xbuild

Tags: linux, msbuild, mono, xbuild

I'm trying to build a C# project using xbuild/mono on Linux. Despite not having any code with the term "ProjectWeaverXml" in my .csproj file, I keep getting this error.

`/home/user/Downloads/ProjectA/ProjectA/ProjectA.csproj: Unable to parse condition "Exists($(ProjectWeaverXml))" : Expected a property at position 8 in condition "Exists($(ProjectWeaverXml))". Missing opening parantheses after the '$'.`

I can't find anything even remotely related on Google. Does anyone have a clue what this error could be referring to?

Comment: What's the output of `mono --version`? Besides, in 2022 you shouldn't use Mono any more. Migrate everything to .NET 6 and issues like that will disappear.